# When preimage of a point is a closure of an open set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Is there some simple criterion or sufficient condition for a preimage of a point under continuous map to be a closure of an open set?

That is, it's obviously closed, and it's not always a closure of an open, but is there something simple one could check?

P.S. I implicitly assume $T_1$ axiom so that singletons be closed.

Comment: It's not necessarily true in general topological spaces that the pre-image of a point is closed because it's not necessarily true that a set consisting of a single point is closed.  A space in which all points are closed is called a $T_1$ space, and not all topological spaces are $T_1$.  So we need to know more about your space to help.  Are you working in $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual topology?

Comment: @RobertShore, yes, I know about this $T_1$ limitation, I just implicitly assumed $T_1$. Sorry, should've written it in the post. Let's say I work in a completely metrizable space.

Comment: @RobertShore, although answers for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual topology are also most welcome :)

Comment: I think you're gonna have a hard time trying to find conditions even for a general continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider e.g. cases where the preimages are $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \cup \{ 2 \}$.

Comment: In a completely metrizable space, for any closed set A and point x, it is possible to define the distance d(A,x). By saying your function in into $\mathbb{R}$, we can define $f(x) = 0$ if x is in A, and $f(x) = d(A,x)$ otherwise. Then f is continuous and the preimage of 0 under f is A. This means any closed set is the preimage of a point, in a completely metrizable space, so the fact that it's the preimage of a point doesn't help you at all. Your question is the same as asking when a general closed set is the closure of an open set. Which I guess there isn't a nice answer to.

Comment: @ZoeAllen, yes, I thought about this today and reached the conclusion that the question is stupid. I am not sure whether it's better to close it or delete it altogether.